# SCL in redhat 7 do not seem to work

Tags: rhel, repository, php7, scl

I wanted to install PHP on a fresh install of Redhat 7. I looked at different options - remi, webtatic and SCL. I decided to go for SCL using- `https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php70/` but it doesn't seem to work.

I installed the OS, registered the system, updated the system and then followed the guide to enable the rhscl repo. But there is no `rh-php7`package available. I looked through the available packages and there is no php7 anywhere.

Can it be that our subscription does not have access to the SCL 2.3 but only to 2.2? 
It sounds strange but seems like the only explanation at this point.

Comment: rh-php7 : The package name is **rh-php70** https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php70/

Comment: sure, but I did a grep for php and got only the 5x versions.

Comment: Also see [How to update Apache to 2.4.29 using SCL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412122/56041) and [Where is php.ini when SCL PHP is in effect?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412169/56041) The first one provides my field notes for upgrading Apache, Python and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you really enabled the RHSCL repo (you can check using `yum repolist enabled`).

The instructions at softwarecollections.org are a bit sparse. I suggest you follow the official installation instructions in [RHSCL Release Notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/2.3_Release_Notes/chap-Installation.html). (You need to attach the appropriate subscription to your system before you can actually enable the repo -- the Release Notes describe this.)

See also [How to use Red Hat Software Collections (RHSCL) or Red Hat Developer Toolset (DTS)?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/472793) for a list of all subscriptions that provide RHSCL.

To answer your last question -- no, it's not possible that you would only have access to RHSCL 2.2 but not 2.3. As long as your subscription gives you access to the product, you will have the latest version available.

Comment: Thank you. 
It is just as I feared, `subscription-manager repos --list` does not show any scl repo.. :(

Comment: @user306541 - You may need `yum -y install centos-release-scl` followed by `yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`. They are the commands for CentOS, and I am guessing Red Hat needs similar.