# How to update Apache and PHP using SCL?

Tags: centos, package-management, repository, scl

I'm testing an upgrade of PHP using SCLs. The testing is happening on a local VM so its OK to break things as we develop a procedure. Following [The SCL Repositories](https://www.hogarthuk.com/?q=node/15) I was able to update Python to 2.7.13 and activate it through `profiles.d/`. I'm now trying to upgrade Apache and PHP.

According to [Apache Downloads](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) the latest is Apache 2.4.29. When I attempt to update Apache with `yum install httpd` I am told *Package httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64 already installed and the latest*. And if I use `yum install httpd24` then SCL tries to install Apache 1.18.

`yum search httpd` is not that helpful. It lists the packages (and sometimes notes SCL) but it lacks version numbers.

How does one install the latest Apache and PHP when using SCL programs?

Answer (score 2):

Here are my field notes for the upgrade of Apache, Python and PHP. It also includes `mod_ssl`, but lacks `mod_security`. I cannot find `mod_security` in the SCL.

```
##################################################
# https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703
# https://www.hogarthuk.com/?q=node/15
# https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/03/19/permanently-enable-a-software-collection/

##################################################
# Enable SCL
##################################################
yum -y install centos-release-scl
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

##################################################
# Python 2.7
##################################################
yum -y install python27

# Add enable-scl-python27.sh
cat /etc/profile.d/enable-scl-python27.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source scl_source enable python27

##################################################
# PHP 7.1
##################################################
yum -y install rh-php71 rh-php71-php rh-php71-ssl rh-php71-php-mysqlnd

# Config at /etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.ini

# Add enable-scl-php71.sh
cat /etc/profile.d/enable-scl-php71.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source scl_source enable rh-php71

##################################################
# Apache 2.4
##################################################
yum -y install httpd24
yum -y install httpd24-httpd-tools httpd24-mod_php httpd24-mod_ssl

# Add enable-scl-php71.sh
cat /etc/profile.d/enable-scl-httpd24.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source scl_source enable httpd24

# Disable old, enable new
systemctl disable httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd24-httpd.service

# Config at /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
#        or /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

# Config at /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

##################################################
# httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

# The original ssl.conf probably includes this:
# SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

# Change it to this:
# /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

##################################################
# !!! TEST APACHE !!!
apachectl configtest

# ps -aux | egrep 'apache|http'
root      1424  0.1  1.2 319644 13376 ?        Ss   00:54   0:00 /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1425  0.0  0.8 361184  8400 ?        Sl   00:54   0:00 /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
...

##################################################
# Backup fresh CONF
##################################################
cp /etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.ini /etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.ini.bu
cp /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.bu
cp /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.bu

##################################################
# Copy old CONF to new CONF
##################################################
# Copy httpd.conf and ssl.conf from /etc/httpd to /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd
# Change SERVER_ROOT from /etc/httpd to /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd
# Leave DOCUMENT_ROOT unchanged. The new server can serve from the old location.
# Leave mod_ssl unchanged. The old and new mod_ssl use /etc/pki/tls/certs and /etc/pki/tls/private.
# php.ini is too different between version 5 and version 7. Manually copy the hardening.

##################################################
# Hardening
##################################################
# List unneeded functions from PHP in disable_functions
# Comment unneeded modules in /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d

##################################################
# Important Diff's after cp
##################################################
diff /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.bu /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
diff /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.bu /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```