# Can't find php-zip extension for php 7.1 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum, php7

I am attempting to install Magento 2.2.5 on a new CentOS 7 server with PHP 7.1. I can't seem to find how to install and/or enable the `php-zip` extension.

The issue I'm trying to resolve is this (via composer):

> magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

The repo I'm using (remi-php71) doesn't seem to have the extension, or maybe it's included in another package. I have searched the webtatic repo as well. How can I install and enable the php-zip extension?

Comment: We had a lot of problems with Remi on CentOS 7. We ended up removing it because we never got the cutover/migration to work. We eventually switched to the [RedHat's SCL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412122/56041).

Comment: Thanks for the info I have moved away from remi. Ended up finding a guide from Magento that worked

Comment: An FYI... I never was able to migrate MySQL/MariaDB using SCL. I was able to install the updated MySQL, but we could not get PHP and Wikimedia to use it. The old MySQL kept starting and PHP and Wikimedia kept trying to use the old MySQL. I was not able to track down why/where it was happening. Too many hard-coded [incorrect] paths, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding my server and I found a guide that worked using the ius repository:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html

```
yum install -y http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update

yum -y install php71u php71u-pdo php71u-mysqlnd php71u-opcache php71u-xml php71u-mcrypt php71u-gd php71u-devel php71u-mysql php71u-intl php71u-mbstring php71u-bcmath php71u-json php71u-iconv php71u-soap
```

Comment: The IUS was another repository we considered when looking at options.. We went with SCL because it is Red Hat's work, and not an outside organization's work.

Comment: In the future I am side-stepping this upgrade mess with Red Hat and CentOS. I am going to rent a Fedora VM and use it in production. Fedora stays on top of their updates and there's no need to install extra software in unusual locations like `/opt/rh`. Every 6 months a [system upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) is needed. I've never had a problem on my personal Fedora machines, and I have been doing them for 5 years or so. The system upgrade is about 5 or 6 commands and takes less than a hour.

Comment: And he we go with more troubles: [Website or Wiki may have problems](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/hZ36JcMwqfk/3ZGyQwMBAwAJ). Red Hat and CentOS suck. I wish the server was a Fedora system with modern software instead of Red Hat and CentOS with antiquated software.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, I had to discover that the package is named `php-pecl-zip` in RHEL8...