# Where is php.ini when SCL PHP is in effect?

Tags: centos, package-management, repository, scl

We enabled SCL on CentOS 7 and installed Python 2.7, Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.1. It looks like the updated programs are being used. However, we seem to have a problem with PHP hardening.

First, here is the `php.ini` we can find:

```
# find /opt/rh -name php.ini
/opt/rh/rh-php71/register.content/etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.ini
```

Next, we added our `disable_functions`:

```
# grep disable_functions /opt/rh/rh-php71/register.content/etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.ini
disable_functions=apache_note,apache_setenv,chgrp,closelog,debugger_off,debugger
_on,define_sys,define_syslog_variables,diskfreespace,dl,escapeshellarg,escapeshe
llcmd,exec,getmypid,getmyuid,ini_restore,leak,listen,openlog,passthru,pclose,pcn
tl_alarm,pcntl_exec,pcntl_fork,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_setp
riority,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigtimedwait,
pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_wait,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcnt
l_wifexited,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_wtermsig,php
_uname,popen,posix,posix_ctermid,posix_getcwd,posix_getegid,posix_geteuid,posix_
getgid,posix_getgrgid,posix_getgrnam,posix_getgroups,posix_getlogin,posix_getpgi
d,posix_getpgrp,posix_getpid,posix_getpwnam,posix_getpwuid,posix_getrlimit,posix
_getsid,posix_getuid,posix_isatty,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setegid,posix_se
teuid,posix_setgid,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_times,posix_tty
name,posix_uname,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,s
hell_exec,show_source,syslog,system,url_exec,_getppid
```

Finally, when we restart Apache, add a `phpinfo.php` page, and then [inspect the result](https://www.cryptopp.com/cryptopp.php) (this is the real web server result), PHP claims there are no disabled functions:

[image]

I think we are using the wrong `php.ini`, but I can't seem to find the one we are supposed to be using. I can't find it on the filesystem in `/opt` and search is returning irrelevant results.

My question is, where is `php.ini` when SCL PHP is in effect?

Comment: Have you checked in `/etc/opt/rh`? (Yeah, SCL configuration is confusing… I think the ones you found are only the templates copied there at "some" point, possibly on installation.)

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich. Yes, it was in `/etc` as opposed to `/opt`. Do you feel like providing an answer? If needed, here are some of my [field notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412171/56041) for the upgrade, including your feedback.

Comment: If you look at the top of the phpinfo() page you'll see the path of the ini file that is loaded/read ....

Answer (score 3):

Software collections install most of their things underneath `/opt`, but the configuration actually lives underneath `/etc/opt`. (And I wouldn't be surprised to see a `/var/opt` either.)
The file you found is actually the configuration that is copied into `/etc/opt/…` by one of the installation scripts in `/opt/rh/rh-php71/register.d`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @ulrich-schwarz provided the correct answer, but to expand on his a bit for others who come across this later like I did and didn't see the answer right away.

When the Software Collections are installed, there is a `php.ini` in the `/opt/rh/...` directory structure, but as he pointed out, it exists in the `/etc/opt/rh/` directory.

In my case, I found that the `rh-php56-php` package placed the php.ini in `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini` - simply adding `disable_functions = "phpinfo"` to the file disabled the function.

To validate this, in `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/` create a `index.php` with this contents:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    echo '<p>Hello World - '.date('F Y h:i:s A').' </p>';
    phpinfo();
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

A fresh install should produce a page with the current date/time followed by the `phpinfo()` blocks of text.

Now edit the `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini` file (substituting in the proper version number), and change the `disable_functions` line to `disable_functions = "phpinfo"`.

Now restart the HTTP server, `systemctl restart httpd24-httpd.service` and reload the web page.  The time should still be displayed, but the block of `phpinfo()` text should be missing.

This should also apply to the `rh-php70-php`, `rh-php71-php`, `rh-php72-php`, and `rh-php73-php` packages - adjust the `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php##` path accordingly.